# How to update the view on callback on the first run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I want to get the search result from service when the page loads. To update the view I need to call `$apply` from the callback only once to avoid `Error: [$rootScope:inprog]`. I tried ng-init, but seems it doesn't call digest loop. Is there a better way of doing it? What's the approach with handling callbacks?

Code:

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" ng-keyup="search()" ng-model="query" spellcheck="false" type="text">
```

and js

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, Contacts) {
    $scope.hits = [];
    $scope.query = '';
    $scope.initRun = true;
    $scope.search = function() {
      Contacts.search($scope.query, function(success, content) {
        if (!success || $scope.query != content.query) {
          return;
        }
        $scope.hits = content.hits;
        if ($scope.initRun){
          $scope.$apply();
          $scope.initRun = false;
        }
      });
    };
    $scope.search();
});
```

Live demo http://lukasz-madon.github.io/algolia-angular-example/#/

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion rather than using `$scope.$apply()` try and use `$scope.$apply(function(){ 'digest loop' });` this is more appropriate way of doing it.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: $scope.$apply() might rise an exception if the variable in the scope isn't defined, so angular throws an error.